# Extract unique strings from array in Excel (2013)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a table of values in the format:

```
Source |Option 1|Option 2|Option 3
-------|--------|--------|--------
France |  AA    |   BB   |  CC
Wales  |  BB    |   CC   |
Britain|  CC    |   AA   |
Greece |  BB    |        |
```

I need them in the format:

```
Outcome | Count |
--------|-------|
 AA     |  2    | 
 BB     |  3    |     
 CC     |  3    |      
 DD     |  0    |
```

**Where the outcome column and count columns are generated from a formula**

I currently cannot work out how to use pivot tables (my first idea) to do a output of the unique outcomes as it doesn't seem to work for an array in the way I intend.

Comment: See [Why Not Images of Code and Sample Data](http://tinyurl.com/kdxb7le) and [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors) and [mcve] and [ask].

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having with your layout is that the text labels in B1:D1 cannot be easily parsed to retrieve a value. To rectify this format B1:C1 with a custom number format of `W\ei\g\ht=0` then type 1, 2 and 3 into them as values.

With the column header labels as true numbers (and only displayed as text), the formulas in G8:G8 become,

```
=COUNTIF($B$2:$D$5, $E8)
=SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$D$5=$E8)*$B$1:$D$1)
'alternate with text labels remaining but a 1, 2, 3 result based on position
=SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$D$5=$E8)*COLUMN($A:$C))
```

Fill down as necessary.

[image: sump_count_matrix]

There are text parsing functions available that could pull the *1, 2* or *3* from *Weight-1, Weight-2, Weight-3, etc* but the calculation load is simply not worthwhile when there other readily available (and easier!) methods available .

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I understand a bit more now about how to use weighting for this. I have updated my question to be more clear on the difficulty I am having which is to do with pulling the unique values from the table and displaying them as a column.